# Illegal character in opaque part at index 2 pipeline

Tags: android, native, cicd

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/runner/work/MobileApp-Android/MobileApp-Android/app/build.gradle' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: E:\files\android_keystore\n.jks

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

**here is my yml file**

name: CI
on:
push:
branches: [ main ]
pull_request:
branches: [ main ]

workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout the code
uses: actions/checkout@v3

```
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew

    - name: Run Lint
      run: ./gradlew lint

    - name: Upload html test report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: index.html
        path: app/build/reports/lint-results-debug.html
```

Comment: Hello @everyone that knows this issues, I ask your help in which part I'm missing that cause of this error. thanks